# Asymptotic Distributions of form: $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu, \hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)$

Tags: normal-distribution, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

> Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ iid normals $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ are the MLE. How would one go about finding
>
> $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu, \hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2).$$

When discussing the distributions of the forms $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu)$ and $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)$ it is quite clear to me using the regular tools and theorems:

The MLE are

$$\hat{\mu} = \bar{X} ~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(X_i - \bar{X})^2$$

and the asymptotic distribution are

$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu) & \overset{d}{\Rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2) \\
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2) & \overset{d}{\Rightarrow} N(0, 1).
\end{align*}
$$

But the joint $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu, \hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)$ is not so obvious. How would one calculate this?

Comment: $\sqrt{n}(\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2) \to N(0, 1)$ should be $\sqrt{n}(\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2) \to N(0, 2\sigma^4)$.

The covariance of sample mean and sample variance for normal distribution is actually zero. You can crank out the (inverse) information matrix to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either compute the information matrix or recall that the normal distribution is symmetric, meaning that the off-diagonal entries in the information matrix are equal to...